# Issue using Digit LEDs Raw (op code 163) on Create2

Tags: irobot-create

If I understand [the manual](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/create_2_Open_Interface_Spec.pdf), each leg in each of the 7 segment displays is labeled with a letter A-G.  These letters then map to specific bits in a byte - 1 byte for each of the 4 displays.  Setting a bit turns on the corresponding leg while not setting it leaves it off.

With this understanding, I tried to turn on all the A segments by sending

```
[163][1][1][1][1]
```

Instead of the A segment in each display turning on, the displays all showed a 1. Further testing shows that if I send the numbers 1-9 for any of the displays, they will display the number sent.  Sending the number 10 or greater turns on various combinations of the segments.

I was able to activate individual segments with the following numbers:

```
63 G
64 A
65 B
66 C
67 D
68 E
69 F
```

However, I haven't been able to determine how the bytes sent affect the individual segments. Either I don't understand the manual or **Digit LEDs Raw** does not work as the manual specifies.

**UPDATE 03JUNE2016**

I have confirmed this behavior exists in the following firmware versions:

- r3-robot/tags/release-3.4.1:5858 CLEAN
- r3_robot/tags/release-3.2.6:4975 CLEAN

Comment: Not that there were any relevant changes to this command, but you should use the most up to date manual which is available at http://www.irobot.com/create.

Comment: @Ben: While I agree that "use the most up to date manual" is always good advice, I can't find the words "manual" or "datasheet" or "spec" anywhere on page http://www.irobot.com/create .

Comment: @DavidCary I agree it is a little confusing.  I point people to http://irobot.com/create because that link should always be valid, and will be redirected to wherever we put our current Create page (for example: http://www.irobot.com/About-iRobot/STEM/Create-2.aspx).  Which you can see may be deprecated if there is ever a Create-3.

Comment: To get to the current documentation, click on the "Get Started" link, then "Create 2 Open Interface Spec".

Answer (score 1):

Opcode 163 has a known bug in it and should not be used.

Comment: Ben, can you link to any bug tracker or other documentation that shows the bug, what the bug causes, and an indication if/when the bug got resolved?

Comment: @Chuck Unfortunately, we don't have a bug tracker.  But the [latest OI Spec](http://www.irobotweb.com/-/media/MainSite/PDFs/About/STEM/Create/iRobot_Roomba_600_Open_Interface_Spec.pdf) document indicates this as a known bug in the description of opcode 163, and in the list of known bugs in Appendix B.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see here, it appears that the manual does not reflect the behavior that you are seeing.  The sequence of ASCII values `[163][1][1][1][1]` (`0xA3 0x01 0x01 0x01 0x01`) should produce 4 lit `A` segments on the display, just like you noted.

The behavior you're seeing doesn't even match what the manual says for code `164` (ASCII input).  For all the displays to show a '1', that command would be `0xA4 0x31 0x31 0x31 0x31.`

Comment: A note for op code 164 - I have tested it, and it works as detailed in the manual.  You are correct in that the behavior I am seeing matches neither or the op codes.